# How can I share local image to Firebase and then be able to retrieve whatever device I sign in in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to post images to Firebase real-time database. Until now, I've successfully done that, the images can be shown but only when I still connect the app and not yet reload

I know the reason is because the `uri` I post on database has the type like this:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F58/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/484166561
```

Here's the code in Redux action for adding a post:

```
export const addPost = (postImage, date, description, checkin_location) => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const token = getState().auth.user.token;
        const userId = getState().auth.user.uid;
            const response = await fetch(
                `https://..../users/${userId}/posts.json?auth=${token}`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        postImage,
                        date,
                        description,
                        checkin_location,
                    })
                });

            const resData = await response.json();
            console.log(resData);
            if(!response.ok){
                console.log("reponse isn't ok in post action ", response)
            };

            dispatch({
                type: ADD_POST,
                postData:{
                    id: resData.name,
                    ownerId: userId,
                    postImage,
                    date,
                    description,
                    checkin_location
                }
            })
    }
}
```

What should I do in order to achieve that?

Or to be precise, how can I convert that `uri` link to be say an `url` or at least a type that `Image` component can display even when I reload or sign in by another device

I'm using real-time database and heard of Firestore and Cloud Functions but haven't used it yet

**PLEASE HELP**